# Javascript set valor em Modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3, modal

Tenho o seguinte código javascript:

```
function chamarModal(valor) {

    $('span.nome').text(valor);
    $('#pagamento-modal').modal();
}
```

Como faço para setar esse conteúdo da variável `valor` no meu modal bootstrap?

Tentei o código acima e outros códigos e não deu certo

Meu modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="pagamento-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Registrar Pagamento</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">Deseja realmente registrar o pagamento no valor de  <b><span class="nome"></span></b>? </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="#" type="button"  class="btn btn-primary pay-yes">Sim</a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">N&atilde;o</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Eu quero inserir nesse bloco:

```
<div class="modal-body">Deseja realmente registrar o pagamento no valor de  <b><span class="nome"></span></b>? </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar um **id** ao **< span >**, que irá funcionar.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("#nome").text("13,13");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">

  Deseja realmente registrar o pagamento no valor de <b>
  <span id="nome" class="nome"></span></b> ?

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não estou a ver onde essa variável está a ser definida no seu código. Mas se o que estás a tentar fazer é pegar o valor de uma `string` e adicioná-la no DOM, podes fazê-lo da seguinte maneira:

```js
var resultado = '464866';
document.getElementsByClassName('nome')[0].innerHTML = resultado;
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">Deseja realmente registrar o pagamento no valor de <b><span class="nome"></span></b> ? </div>
```

### Se o caso for pegar o conteúdo/valor de um elemento que já se encontra implementado no DOM:

```js
var resultado = document.getElementsByClassName('nome')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementById('montante_pagar').innerHTML = resultado;
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">Deseja realmente registrar o pagamento no valor de  <b><span class="nome">464866</span></b>? </div>
<br>
<h3>Montante a pagar: <span id="montante_pagar"></span></h3>
```

### Se o caso for obter o valor de um `input`:

```js
document.getElementById('botao').addEventListener("click", minhaFuncao);

function minhaFuncao() {
    var resultado = document.getElementById('obtemValor').value;
    document.getElementsByClassName('nome')[0].innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

```html
<p>quantia a adicionar: <input type="number" id="obtemValor"/></p>
<div class="modal-body">Deseja realmente registrar o pagamento no valor de  <b><span class="nome"></span></b>? </div>
<button id="botao">traz o valor</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Responderei mais como realizar o debug. 
Ao meu ver seu código esta funcional, então o problema esta em outro lugar. que não no trecho de código que você disponibilizou.

Use o console do navegador e execute as linhas uma a uma, analisando na aba elementos se os valores que se alterarão são os do que você esta definindo.

Outra possibilidade é que o seu modal não esta definido no documento e sim em uma variável e o código que nos passou seja apenas um exemplo. Para evitar esse possível problema tente o seu código assim

```
function chamarModal(valor) {
    $('#pagamento-modal').modal().find('span.nome').text(valor);
}
```